# SQL Server Automating a Database Refresh

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to automate the process of restoring a SQL Server database based on the db table definitions on a different server.  Is there a way to:

1. Generate a SQL create script that has the table definitions in a create statement for all the tables in a database?

Or

2. Restore (create new tables and load data) on server A from server B without having to take a backup of server B etc.  That is are there any simple commands that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your 1st question I assume you want to create new database which contains only table schema taken from other database. To achieve this you can generate scripts for all tables using **'Generate scripts'** functionality of SQL Server Management Studio. Just right lick on database name, then go to **'tasks'** -> **'generate scripts...'** Now you can decide about objects you want to script out (tables, views, stored procedures, etc.) and moving forward under **'set scripting options'** -> **'advanced'** tab specify even more detailed options like indexes, constraints, keys, statistics, etc. Eventually you get a script made of CREATE statements which executed on destination database recreates selected objects for you.

In case of your 2nd question I believe that backup - restore operation is simplest and most robust one (and I guess most common approach in case of refreshing databases...). But if for some reason you can't use it you can go for bunch of methods like replication, etc. but none of it would be really simple to implement. To be fair, to answer on this question more precisely you should provide more details about your case.